# Compile source C in a process

Tags: c, unix, exec, fork

I want to compile a source C in a parent process and then , the executable created , I want to run it into a son process. Any ideas?

Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define execle("/bin/ls","bin/ls","-l",NULL);

int main(int argc , char **argv )
{
    int i;
    for(i=1 ; i<argc ; i++)
    {
        if(argv[1]==".c")
        {
            if(fork()==0)
            {
                execle("/usr/bin/gcc","/usr/bin/gcc",argv[1],NULL);
                exit(1);
            }    
        }

        if(argv[2]==".out")
        {
            if(fork()==0)
            {
                execle("/bin/cat","bin/cat/",argv[2],NULL);
                exit(1);
            }
        }
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

Here is how the code looks like , but can you tell me why it gives me errors on the lines where execle(..) is ?

Comment: write it out to a file, system out to the compiler, remove the source file and execute the binary produced (assuming the compile worked)?

Comment: Technically, what you want doesn't make sense. After the compiler has finished, the compiler process will no longer exist, so it will not be able to have any children because it will not exist. You could do them both in child processes though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your parent/driver program, use the `system(3)` call or a combination of `fork/exec/wait` to run your compiler. Then you can use the same calls to run the newly compiled executable.

Keep in mind the security aspects of this while implementing it. This kind of thing has a huge exploit potential.

Answer (score 1):

```
#define execle("/bin/ls","bin/ls","-l",NULL);
```

What do you expect this line to do ?

These two lines

```
if(argv[1]==".c")
if(argv[2]==".out")
```

Don't do what you think

try

```
if( strcmp(".c" , argv[1]) == 0 )
if( strcmp(".out" , argv[2]) == 0 )
```

More : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcmp/

Also,

```
exec("/bin/cat","bin/cat/",argv[2],NULL);
```

Does not really exist, so change it to `execle` and `#include <stdint.h>`

More : http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/ForkExecProcesses.html

You should end up with something like :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc , char **argv)
{
    int i;
    for(i=1 ; i<argc ; i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(".c" , argv[1]) == 0)
        {
            if(fork()==0)
            {
                execle("/usr/bin/gcc","/usr/bin/gcc",argv[1],NULL);
                exit(1);
            }    
        }

        if(strcmp(".c" , argv[1]) == 0)
        {
            if(fork()==0)
            {
                execle("/bin/cat","bin/cat/",argv[2],NULL);
                exit(1);
            }
        }
    } 
    return 0;
}
```